# jQUery/Javascript Variable problem

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am trying to fix some bugs regarding javascript variable . Hope someone can help me , please read:

Here's my problem ,
I am using jQuery cookies plugin by Klaus Hartl.
and i want to activate a function when certain cookies value is "VALID". However , when i assign an existing

Here's the code:

```
var cookie1 = 'first';
var cookie1val = $.cookie(cookie1);
var cookieOp = {expires: 7, path:'/'}; //this is cookies options

//when click button , cookie plugin will assign VALUE : VALID to cookie 1
$('.button').click(function() {
  $.cookie(cookie1 , 'valid' , cookieOp);
});

$(document).ready(function(){
  if (cookie1val == 'valid'){
     alert('cookie one value is valid!');
  }
  else{
  //do nothing
  }
});
```

But when i run this , (p/s i had included cookie plugin script to my page) , firebugs says "**$.cookie(cookie1)**" is not a function(in the variable)

then i try :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      if ($.cookie(cookie1) == 'valid'){
         alert('cookie one value is valid!');
      }
      else{
      //do nothing
      }
    });
```

same thing happened . :(

So please someone please help me point out my mistakes , thanks!

Comment: In what order are you including jQuery / the cookie plugin on your page? Make sure you're including jQuery first.

Comment: are you sure you have added this code before jQuery plugin files

Comment: show us how you included it in the page. Are you sure you got the directory exactly right? Does Firebug show that it loaded with a 200 (not 404 or any other error)

Comment: Just check to see that the plug-in loads before you use it.

Comment: Yes all plugin loads before the custom code and yes jQuery script is added

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you load your custom code after the Cookie plugin, and the Cookie plugin after jQuery. Can't see anything wrong in the code with a quick glimpse at least.